# Changing place of boxes tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating an app and this is the part of it. I will put a canvas up to the screen so I want these variables to be at the bottom of the page but when I run this code it places everything on top left corner as shown in the photo(figure1). I am using grid function but I couldn't understand why it doesn't place where I want.(Sorry for bad english)

```
main = Tkinter.Tk()
main.geometry("1500x1000")
main.title("Momentum")

ml1 = Tkinter.Label(main, text ="MASS OF THE FIRST OBJECT")
ml2 = Tkinter.Label(main, text ="MASS OF THE SECOND OBJECT")
me1 = Tkinter.Entry(main)
me2 = Tkinter.Entry(main)
ml1.grid(row=600, column =400)
ml2.grid(row =600, column =600 )
me1.grid(row=650, column =400)
me2.grid(row=650, column=600)
main.mainloop()
```

[image: figure1]

Comment: Tkinter does not display empty rows or columns.  Use rowconfigure to show an empty row i.e. main.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)